# One question about Schrodinger Semigroups-(B. Simon)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

This question comes from the paper: B. Simon, [Schrodinger Semigroups](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183549767), Bull. A.M.S., (1982) Vol. 7 (3).

On the **Theorem C.3.4**(subsolution estimate) of the paper, it says that: Let $Hu=Eu$ and $u\in L^2$, where $H=-\Delta+V$ for some bounded continuous function $V$, if $E$ is in discrete spectrum of $H$.  Then for some $C,~\delta>0$
$$|u(x)|\leq Ce^{-\delta|x|}.$$

**Q**

- How to get constant $C$, does it depend $\delta$?
- Is there any estimate about $C$, especially without the condition on the compactness of $supp(E-V)_+$?

*PS*:
 I can follow how to get $\delta$. I can understand that $e^{\delta |x|}u\in L^\infty$.  I do not know how to get the constant $C$, as the equation is linear, if we multiply any positive number $k$ with $u$,  it is also a solution for the equation,  where I can not follow. 
 And I think $C$ depends on the $L^2$-norm of $u$.

Comment: Assuming $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$, this comes from an argument using the Agmon metric: since this bound is easier to show in the 1-dimensional case, you extend the result to higher dimensions by approximating your eigenfunction using the WKB method. 

A good place to read about this is Hislops "Introduction to Spectral Theory." Theorem 3.10 is the result you want, and the geometric hypothesis (the condition on $\text{supp}(E-V(x))_+$) of this theorem requires is implied by your potential $V$ being bounded. 

The constant $C$ does depend on $\delta$.

Comment: @HadrianQuan Thank you for the comment and reference. But I still have one question, if we  multiply any positive number $k$ with the function $u$, it is still a solution of that equation.So, how to get the constant ($\delta$ comes from the spectrum of $H$).

Comment: @DLIN $u$ is assumed to be normalized. This also gives you a hint on the dependence on $\delta$

Comment: @lcv Well, from that paper, I have not seen any hypothesis on the norm of $u$. By the way, do you mean the theorem needs the assumption that $\|u\|_{L^2}=1$.

Comment: The theorem as stated does not need it. But if you want to see how $C$ depends on $\delta$ you can simply normalize both sides.